# Beginner: Wrong workflow? 8x8x8 LED Cube to complex

Tags: workflow, performance

Total beginner here - I hope you guys can help me :)

So I want to make a 3D representation of my **LED Cube**. It consists of 512 LEDs (8x8x8). I think it should be pretty simple... So I started reading a Tutorial and now I just created the 3D LED cube. But the performance seems pretty bad - thats why **I think I am using Blender wrong** :)

---

*My Workflow:*
I deleted the standard scene and then added a UV Sphere
I reduced the segments and Rings to 12 and reduced the size to 0.25.
I hoped that this would make the performance better (I want to export it to a .obj file and use it in a C# Program).
Then I duplicated the singe LED and created a row, changed the position of each new LED. When the row was done I created an 8x8 LED side by duplicating the row 7 times. Then I duplicated the first side 7 times to get my 8x8x8 cube.

My object looks like this:
[image: Object in Blender]
I see that the verts/edges/faces count is pretty high - I assume this is bad for my performance. Is there a better workflow for my little project that results in a better performance? My **exported Object is 4.91 MB big** - seems a little big for a simple cube or is this ok?

Sorry but I would really appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: I would have picked an icosphere, or even tetrahedron as the LED unit.  It mostly depends on how it will be used.  A lot of beginners put too much detail on things that never is noticable.

Comment: Thank you @MutantBob . Just created a new Cube using icospheres and the performance is a **lot** better. No more frame drops :) I'll test some things here and there but your comment gave me a noticeable improvement!

Comment: Both of the answers suggested reducing the number of faces.  A base icosahedron has 20 triangles which is a drastic reduction from 144.  A dodecahedron would have 12 faces but 36 triangles.  An octahedron has 8;  A cube has 12 triangles; and a tetrahedron 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly see no problem with this, there is not much you can do except
for making the mesh at a lower resolution, 
you do not mention what engine you are using this in, but one option might be to look in the engine you use, then see if it supports instancing of meshes which then can have separate materials assigned (I assume you are assigning materials to the different LED's during runtime.).

The you only export one LED, then create it all by code (instance,move the instance, assign materials and so on). That way the mesh memory is kept low, because it will only load 1 LED mesh.

But again - this scene is not big at all compared to other game content that typically exists in a scene.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback, I really appreciate it. I wanted to use this 3D Object with WPF and C#. I am using the Helix-Toolkit to load the .obj file because I was not able to load the object without this toolkit in visual studio 2015. But I'm getting like 3 FPS when I'm rotating the camera right now :/. I might have to try your tip with instancing the LEDs seperatly - thanks again

Answer (score 2):

12 segments and 12 rings sphere has 144 faces. 512 of those spheres sum up to 73728 faces. Is it possible that you export one sphere and do the instancing within your program?

And by the way 12 segments and 6 rings would yield better topology. Number of rings better be half of the number of segments.